# How to create similar vertical slideshow in iOS & Android?

Tags: android, ios, tabs, slide

What is the particular term or name for me to research? I tried with more than 50 different keywords and combination which including "vertical, image, slideshow, slider, tab", but I couldn't find a similar source.

May I know is there any available library and resources to create the similar vertical slide with the clickable element ?

[image: Vertical Image Slider Menu]

Comment: Check here, there are a lot of libraries maybe can it help...https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: What a swift respond! @Aspicas Thanks for the list of library, searching one by one now.

Comment: Totally agreed :P I think the similar one is called Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager @Skynet

Comment: aa.. Headerview pager is different from the above. That is for the Toolbar :) Like the Google Play Stand app!

Comment: no, I agree with @Skynet, that library it's for toolbar design not for listviews, try to find another one

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) is something close to what you want

Comment: I notice the great sample you gave is working well, just don't have the "bouncing" effect when the scroll hang in the middle. How can we achieve that? For example user scroll half way and the app will automatically finish the scroll.. @Skynet